# Limitar quantidade máxima de linhas numa textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, textarea

Tenho uma textarea na qual eu limitei a quantidade para 3 linhas na propriedade "rows". Porém, não está sendo respeitada essa quantidade máxima. Existe alguma outra maneira de não permitir que pulem mais linhas?

```
<textarea id="txtValue" onPaste="return onPasteMe(this);"   ondrop="return false" maxlength="180" style="overflow:scroll; resize: none;width:650px; font-family:'Courier New';border-width:1px; border-color:black; font-family:monospace;font-size:18pt" rows="3" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: O atributo `rows` é usado pra definir quantas linhas(height em linhas) esse `textarea` terá ao ser renderizado, não seria melhor definir um limite de caracteres no `textarea` que atenda a sua necessidade?

Comment: entendi... Já defini, porém ele está limitado pela quantidade máxima de caracteres, mas ele permite que eu quebre quantas linhas quiser. quero limitar para 3 linhas no máximo.

Comment: O textarea passará de 3 linhas, se o seu **maxlength** extrapolar as 3 linhas `(maxlenght="180")`, terá que limitar o maxlength ao máximo das 3 linhas `(maxlength="150")` por exemplo ou aumentar as linhas para caber os 180.

Comment: Vc quer que o usuário não consiga dar `enter` para quebrar a linha dentro do textarea, ou vc quer que o conteúdo não ultrapasse mais que 3 linhas dentro do textarea?

Comment: que o conteúdo não ultrapasse 3 linhas dentro da textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `jquery` e o atributo `maxlength` para controlar as quebras de linhas, o problema é que depende da quantidade de carácteres que cada linha aceita, para isso você terá que calcular o `maxlength` baseado no tamanho da linha,  mas tenta adaptar isso para a tua necessidade:

```
//seta o total de caracteres aceitos
<textarea id="textareaid" maxlength="300" ></textarea>

//bloqueia o resize do textarea para deixar o tamanho de colunas fixo
//para fazer o calculo de quantos caracteres a linha aceita
textarea {
   resize: none;
}

//bloqueia a quebra de linha
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#textareaid').keydown(function(e) {

        var linhasAtuais = $(this).val().split("\n").length;

        if(e.keyCode == 13 && linhasAtuais >= 3) {
            return false;
        } 
    });
 });
```

Não me parece bonito ou o modo correto, mas é um jeito.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e924pjyw/

Comment: Obrigado!! Era exatamente isso que estava querendo fazer

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é não permitir a quebra de linha usando jquery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#txtValue").keypress(function(e){                
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {                
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

ou com javascript:

```
<script>
function bloquearQuebraDeLinha(event) {
    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {                
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
<textarea id="txtValue" onkeypress="bloquearQuebraDeLinha(event);" onPaste="return onPasteMe(this);"   ondrop="return false" maxlength="100" style="overflow:scroll; resize: none;width:650px; font-family:'Courier New';border-width:1px; border-color:black; font-family:monospace;font-size:18pt" rows="3" max-rows="3" wrap="hard"runat="server"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

O atributo `rows` especifica o número visível de linhas em uma área de texto, o que você está tentando fazer não tem nada haver com o seu problema. Para limitar a quantidade de caracteres no elemento `textarea`, você pode limitar a quantidade de caracteres utilizando o atributo `maxlength`no elemento `textarea`.

Neste exemplo limitei a quantidade de caracteres de no **máximo 3:**

```js
const txtArea = document.getElementById('txtArea');
txtArea.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if(event.code == 'Enter') {
        alert("O BOTÃO ENTER FOI CLICADO! QUEBRANDO A LINHA...");
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea" maxlength="10" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Sobre quebrar a linha quando clicar no botão "enter", esta funcionalidade não precisa ser implementada, isto já é pré-programado. Veja a animação abaixo, utilizando o código acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para prevenir a quebra de linha você deve adicionar o `preventDefault()` no `event`, deste modo:

```js
const txtArea = document.getElementById('txtArea');
txtArea.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if(event.code == 'Enter') {
        alert("O BOTÃO ENTER FOI CLICADO! QUEBRANDO A LINHA...");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea" maxlength="10" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: já está limitada a quantidade de caracteres o problema é conseguir quebrar mais de 3 linhas.

Comment: @RafaelVeloso o que você quer dizer com "quebrar" ?

Comment: pular linha quando apertar o enter

Comment: @RafaelVeloso veja novamente a minha resposta..